# Can I deny access to an Assembly attribute from outside the assembly it is applied to?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Can I mark an assembly attribute (like `[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("key", "value")]`) as private/internal to make it only accessible from within the assembly it is applied to?

Background:
I have just tested a technique to get some build information in code (e.g. the solution directory) via the `AssemblyMetadata` attribute and a custom msbuild target by adding the following class to the project and msbuild target to the *.csproj file:

```
static class BuildEnvironment
{
    static string _solutionDir;

    public static string SolutionDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_solutionDir == null)
                _solutionDir = Initialize();
            return _solutionDir;

            string Initialize()
            {
                var metadata = typeof(BuildEnvironment).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyMetadataAttribute>();
                return metadata.FirstOrDefault((x) => x.Key == "SolutionDir")?.Value ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}


<Target Name="GenerateBuildEnvironment" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyMetadata">
            <_Parameter1>SolutionDir</_Parameter1>
            <_Parameter2>$(SolutionDir)</_Parameter2>
        </AssemblyAttributes>
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)" Language="C#" OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="Compile" />
    </WriteCodeFragment>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I mark an assembly attribute (like `[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("key", "value")]`) as private/internal to make it only accessible from within the assembly it is applied to?

No.  The point of metadata is that it needs to be readable from .NET itself or external tools such as *Reflector* or *JetBrains DotPeek*. Metadata is by definition *public*. To hide it defeats the purpose.

If you want such information private, don't use .NET assembly attributes.  You could store it as a resource and protect it using your favourite protection method.